# Chef Guard for Windows Firewall with Custom GUID

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am able to create a custom Windows Firewall rule with Chef and Powershell.  I am having a problem with not_if.

I have used the Registry key methods from here:
http://docs.opscode.com/resource_registry_key.html

A custom firewall rule creates a registry key with a random GUID.  I am not able to use the methods because I do not know the key name.  The key value will be the same on each node, but not the key name.

The following works.  But a custom key has a GUID for the key name

```
execute "enableMSDTCFirewall" do
        command "netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=\"Distributed Transaction Coordinator\" new enable=yes"
        action :run
        not_if { registry_data_exists?("HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\FirewallRules", {:name => 'MSDTC-In-TCP', :type => :string, :data => "v2.20|Action=Allow|Active=TRUE|Dir=In|Protocol=6|App=%SystemRoot%\\system32\\msdtc.exe|Name=@FirewallAPI.dll,-33503|Desc=@FirewallAPI.dll,-33506|EmbedCtxt=@FirewallAPI.dll,-33502|"})}
end
```

Other then a flag, I cannot figure out another way to check if the rule exists and not have the script execute during each client run.  Any ideas?

Ended up with this working

```
execute "enableFirewallRuleNameOutbound" do
    command "powershell.exe New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName \"RuleName\" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 20000 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow"
    action :run
    not_if 'netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=\"RuleName\" > nul'
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing the rule has a name you are not using and or could use to help out. Something like the following should work.

When adding the rule, give it a name:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=enableMSDTCFirewall ...
```

Checking for the rule in your not_if:

```
not_if 'netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=enableMSDTCFirewall > nul'
```

The `show` command should return an `ERRORLEVEL` of 0 if the rule already exists.

Comment: You should have single quotes around the 'netsh...' line, not curly-braces.